# What is the cause of a transmission error timeout when connecting to sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I see this error in my logs:

```
[INFO]  2019-10-01T14:29:58.303Z    e8ad5b4e-119a-48c1-b320-1d855c4efb22    Getting SQS queue url from <some_sqs_queue>...
    14:30:16
[CRITICAL]  2019-10-01T14:30:16.743Z    e8ad5b4e-119a-48c1-b320-1d855c4efb22    ## Transmission Error Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/"
```

and this is the relevant code which works locally but not up on the lambda:

```
 sqs = boto3.client(
        'sqs', # region_name="us-west-2",
        aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
        aws_session_token=credentials.token,
        config=Config(connect_timeout=6, read_timeout=10, retries={'max_attempts': 2})
    )
```

and

```
try:
    logger.info(f"Getting SQS queue url from {sqs_queue}...")
    queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=sqs_queue)['QueueUrl']
    # iterate over entries in batches of 10
    for batch in [entries[index:index + sqs_batch_limit] for index in range(0, len(entries), sqs_batch_limit)]:
        logger.info(f"Sending batch of {len(batch)} records to sqs...")
        sqs.send_message_batch(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            Entries=batch
        )
        logger.info("Sent batch of records to sqs successful")
```

It doesn't even get the sqs_queue_url but it works locally. What are the possible reasons for this log Transmission Error Connect error?

Comment: Have you made sure that the credentails used to perform the call have the necessary permissions to access the queues

Comment: I believe they do, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Few things to try:

- Check the permissions on the lambda - You should NOT be putting cli credentials into your lambda. The lambda should be configured to use an IAM Role with the correct access setup, in this case, SQS Read and Write. This is because Lambdas do not inherit permissions the same way as when you run it locally, as they dont have a ".credentials" and ".config" file under your C://users directory which when run locally are automatically picked up.
- Check your queue has got the correct permissions to be accessed. You can check this by going to SQS->Pick Your queue -> Then check the permissions tab.
- Check your lambda is running where it can reach that endpoint. E.g is it in a locked down subnet or VPC? - for more info on what service endpoints AWS use go here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region

Hope one of these might help!

Comment: so I checked my sqs permissions and they say: `arn:aws:sqs:*:<id>:user-id* 
Allow: sqs:*` which I take to mean if any resource begins with user-id (like a lambda) it can do anything on sqs right?

Comment: The lambda is running in a vpc and subnet. I'm not sure if the SQS queue is in the same vpc and subnet. How do I check that? If the lambda is in a subnet and vpc... what should I do?

Comment: An SQS queue doesnt sit inside any VPC or Subnet, its all hosted and maintained by AWS. The only need you need to be aware of for SQS is what region its in. Double check that your lambda has access to the SQS endpoints I linked in the last point. You can do this by doing a ping to the URL in your lambda